# Sort of scheduler

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I need to implement something. Something that could do some certain task in my program. For example every ten seconds, write something into a log in a file.
Of course it suppose to run in a background thread.

Where should I dig? I am not so familiar with multithreading. I've heard about BackgroundWorker class, but I'm not sure if it is appropriate here..

Comment: Sounds like you just need a Timer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use System.Threading.Timer, it will run a task in a ThreadPoool thread. That is the most efficient way for this.

Here is an example, every 10 seconds:

```
Timer aTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(MyTask, null, 0, 10000);

static void MyTask(object state)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually for WPF DispatcherTimer would be much better than the Async timer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the backgroundworker class for this, but it sounds like you just need to use Timer.